# Why I Should every time use GestureHandlerRootView?

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I learn react native gesture handler and react-native-reanimated on youtube. I never see that the guys use GestureHandlerRootView. But if I dont use this, nothing works, so I have to do every time on the top of the return to use this. Why it works at their but not on mee ?